# Concatenation of 2 videos drops all audio

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I've read a number of other answers with similar problems, but they all have other variables/complications that (apparently) I don't understand, because I've had no luck in trying to apply them to the problem.

I'm trying to prepend a 10 second disclaimer video with no audio (created from a png file) to an MP4 video WITH audio, and am losing the audio altogether when I concatenate them.

What I'm doing is:

1. `ffmpeg.exe -i MyDisclaimer.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts temp1.ts`
2. `ffmpeg.exe -i MyVideo.MP4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts temp2.ts`
3. `ffmpeg.exe -i "concat:temp1.ts|temp2.ts" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc "final.mp4"`

Step 2 results in a .ts file that DOES have audio, but something in the 3rd step is ignoring/dropping the audio in the final output.

While creating MyVideo.MP4, I'm using `-acodec copy` to keep the original audio quality.  How can I accomplish the same thing while concatenating, or at least stop losing it altogether?

Here's my output (with long paths removed), and the FFMpeg version is included at the bottom.

```
C:>ffmpeg.exe -i MyDisclaimer.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts temp1.ts
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'MyDisclaimer.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
  Duration: 00:00:10.01, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 57 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 53 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 11988 tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Output #0, mpegts, to 'temp1.ts':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, q=2-31, 53 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 11988 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  300 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=     105kB time=00:00:09.90 bitrate=  86.5kbits/s
video:66kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 59.469032%

C:>ffmpeg.exe -i MyVideo.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts temp2.ts
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'MyVideo.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    title           : EXAMPLE-Testing upload 842
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
  Duration: 00:00:24.73, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1521 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1615:1616 DAR 1615:909], 1487 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 11988 tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (HE-AACv2) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 47 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Output #0, mpegts, to 'temp2.ts':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1615:1616 DAR 1615:909], q=2-31, 1487 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 11988 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, 47 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  731 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=    5027kB time=00:00:24.42 bitrate=1685.8kbits/s
video:4429kB audio:143kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 9.950656%

C:>ffmpeg.exe -i "concat:temp1.ts|temp2.ts" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc "Final.mp4"
[mpegts @ 00000000051362c0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 1 (Audio: aac ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 0 channels): unspecified sample format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, mpegts, from 'concat:temp1.ts|temp2.ts':
  Duration: 00:00:24.39, start: 1.466733, bitrate: 1723 kb/s
  Program 1
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
    Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x101](und): Audio: aac ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 0 channels
[mp4 @ 000000000573a020] Codec for stream 0 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
Output #0, mp4, to 'Final.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1920x1080, q=2-31, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 1031 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=    4511kB time=00:00:34.30 bitrate=1077.4kbits/s
video:4500kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.239671%

FFMPEG VErsion Info
ffmpeg version N-73975-gda8b70b Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54. 28.100 / 54. 28.100
  libavcodec     56. 52.100 / 56. 52.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 27.100 /  5. 27.100
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
```

Comment: All inputs must have the same streams with the same stream parameters. Different players have varying levels of adaptability for streams introduced mid-way or for changing stream properties.

Comment: Okay, the first 2 DO have the same parameters, so how do you concatenate them and keep the original audio of the 2nd video?

Comment: Does your build include support for libfdk_aac? (You omitted the version info so I have to ask. You should always include the complete console output.)

Comment: The version info is at the bottom of the post.  The videos do have varying audio codecs, which is why I'm trying to simply copy the one that the video has.

Comment: The first file, MyDisclaimer.mp4 has no audio. The video streams don't have the same properties - the first is high profile and the 2nd is main but since the H264 decoder is initialized for high, most can cope. For audio, you'll need an encoder like fdk-aac to generate a HE-AACv2 stream like the one that MyVideo.mp4 has.

Comment: Well, we're in over my head now.  When I create the 10 second disclaimer from a png file, is there a way to add a "silent" audio stream to it so that both will have audio?

Comment: Yes, but you'll need to either encode the silent audio as HE-AACv2 (it's why I asked about libfdk_aac), or re-encode the audio from `MyVideo.MP4` to regular AAC (using `-c:a aac`). If the inputs are going to have arbitrary, varying parameters, and you want the outputs to share a set of common parameters (same width, height, etc) you may consider using the concat filter. Downside is it will re-encode everything. Otherwise, make a new `MyDisclaimer.mp4` piecemeal to fit the parameters of each new main video then use the concat demuxer. Which method would you prefer?

Comment: Because all our original videos have varying audio (we copy the audio track), I'd like to create the disclaimer with a silent audio track that matches that, so that it will be an "easier concatenation".  I was about to post that question because simply adding a blank audio track now garbles the resulting audio (at least there IS aduio, lol)

Comment: If you don't mind sacrificing desync in older players, at least older versions of Windows Media Player, you could do this in a roundabout way. If you're interested, I'll post the method.